# Getting Database Tables in combobox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am doing a financial accounting project for my university accounting course, the problem (after reading lots of stuff) is still not resolved is that,

I want to populate combo box with names of table; please help me out.

I know `"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'"` etc.

How to write this query in C# wpf, and using foreach loop  or other logic populate combo box. with Sqlconnnection sql etc.

Please help, I'm writing this query after wasting lots of time in searching google and reading tutorials.

Can you show me how to achieve WPF C# populating TABLES in database?

Comment: IMHO, you cannot execute query(SQL) in WPF directly like WinForms.you should have WCF(webservice) services.

Comment: Wasting time? No, you didn't ... because of your search and all at least now you know the query and little more stuff. Waste little more time and you will be able to achieve your task.

Comment: Guys please refer me some website or link that helps me query sql in wpf which gives me tables name in return so that i can populate my combo box! :$ please!!!!

Comment: @MajidTaheri What do you mean it will work in WinForm but no WPF.  The connection to SQL is .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='Base Table'"
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, sqlConn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Some skeleton code that will probably help, then in wpf you can bind the datatable straight to the combo box.

Comment: Thanks a lot this code helped me out!. Can you tell me what is purpose of line 'code' SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt); 'code'

Comment: SqlDataAdapter is just a simple object to convert a sqlCommand into a DataTable using the Fill method.  Did you have a more specific question about it?

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much walks you through it

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308656

Expose the DataTable as a public property and bind to it.
The displaymemberpath should be the column with the table name.